# Global variable javascript not working appropriately

Tags: javascript, google-maps, global-variables

I am working on a website in which I am trying to incorporate Google maps. The page fetches values from a database using php. It then passes one of the column values to a javascript function which plots it using Google Maps. Now, I want to display the plots of all the values in a single map.

I am attaching the javascript function and the php call. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myOptions;
var map;
var geocoder;
var first_call = 0;

function map_function(addr){
    // Define the addresses we want to map.
    var clubs = addr;
    // Create a new Geocoder
    if (first_call == 0){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }
    // Locate the address using the Geocoder.
    geocoder.geocode( { "address": clubs }, function(results, status) {
        // If the Geocoding was successful
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (first_call == 0){
                // Create a Google Map at the latitude/longitude returned by the Geocoder.
                // Create Once
                alert("Initializing Map");
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                //Initialise once
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            }
            // Add a marker at the address.
            alert("Plotting address");
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
                try {
                    console.error("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                } catch(e) {}
            }
    });
    first_call = first_call + 1;
    alert (first_call);
}
</script>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">map_function("{$addr}");</script>';
?>
```

I know that the map along with its options should be initialized only once. So I am keeping a track of the function call using first_call and making sure that the map is initialized only on the first call. Besides, I am declaring the map, options and the geocoder as global variables. Unfortunately, I do not get any output. I am really new to javascript and I dont know where am I going wrong.

Anxiously awaiting a solution.

Comment: Probably many different problems in this code.  Here's one.  Remove the `var` in this line `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();` so that you are referencing the global variable, not creating a new temporary local variable.

Comment: Second problem.  Same issue for the `map` variable.

Comment: Third problem.  You are adding one to `first_call` at the end of your `map_function()` function, but that occurs BEFORE the geocode operation completes.  You should increment that variable inside the geocode completion callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about php code but your javascript code has several errors.

First of all you define `mapOptions`, `map`, and `geocoder` as global and then redefine each of them locally. So, `var` in front of variables is deleted in function `map_function`.

The next one which prevents that map is initialized at all is update of `first_call` variable.  Because `geocode()` is asynchronous function, `first_call` is set to 1 and then increased further even before code reach the check `if (first_call == 0){`. So the map is never initialized.

Below is changed code with my test code without php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myOptions;
var map;
var geocoder;
var first_call = 0;

function map_function(addr){
    // Define the addresses we want to map.
    var clubs = addr;

    // Create a new Geocoder
    if (first_call == 0){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // var deleted
    }
    // Locate the address using the Geocoder.
    geocoder.geocode( { "address": clubs }, function(results, status) {
        // If the Geocoding was successful
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (first_call == 0){
                // Create a Google Map at the latitude/longitude returned by the Geocoder.
                // Create Once
                console.log("Initializing Map");
                myOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                //Initialise once
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            }
            // Add a marker at the address.
            console.log("Plotting address");
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            first_call = first_call + 1;
            console.log (first_call);
        } else {
                try {
                    console.error("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                } catch(e) {}
            }
    });
    // wrong place because of async call: map is never initialized
    //first_call = first_call + 1;
    //console.log (first_call);
}

var addresses = ['Paris', 'London', 'Berlin'];
for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    map_function(addresses[i]);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I dont really understand what asynchronous functions are but I will surely read it up. Your code worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Async in this case means that `geocoder.geocode()` return immediately and doesn't wait that `function(results, status)` finishes. So `first_call` is increased before check is done inside `function(results, status)`.

Comment: Okay. So thats why the map never initialized. I get it now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of output templating mishap. Nothing big.
I've rewritten it properly for you.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">map_function(' . $addr . ');</script>';
?>
```